# Why the change of layout is not connected at the start of Openbox

Tags: keyboard-layout, openbox

I installed Openbox instead of Gnome on my computer with Ubuntu 22.04.1 that I downloaded yesterday from the official repository. I've installed openbox via apt and I use LightDM to select openbox instead of Gnome.

I've tried to add another layout using this command:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -variant -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

And if I execute it directly in terminal, it works great. But I want it to start with system and not to write it each time I start my computer. So I put it in ~/.config/openbox/autostart
Also I put here some other helpful commands. So it is like:

```
xinput set-prop "Elan Touchpad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1 &
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -variant -option grp:alt_shift_toggle &
lxpanel &
xfce4-power-manager &
```

First line activates tapping on my touchpad.

Third line starts lxpanel

Fourth line starts xfce power manager

All of those commands are executed normally. But the second line isn't. Every time I start computer I can't switch language. But if I execute ~/.config/openbox/autostart manually, it works normally. What the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your account is not yet ready to process the command while you execute it. Instead put your command (as it currently is) in the X startup configuration file `~/.xsessionrc`.

Comment: Yeaaaaah, it works! Thanks!